# Failing to turn on a LED with GPIO Pins (Raspberry Pi 3 B V1.2)

Tags: gpio, pi-3, rpi.gpio, led, breadboard

I'm trying to play around with my RaspberryPi a bit and I'm failing miserably... ANY help ist highly appreciated!

I'm on a brand new installation of Raspbian, after "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade".

I set up the wiring exactly as follows (resistor 330 Ohm):

[image]

I have followed this tutorial exactly: https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/27968772-turning-on-an-led-with-your-raspberry-pis-gpio-pins

The code they suggest is as follows:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
print "LED on"
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(1)
print "LED off"
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
```

I execute the script as follows:

> sudo pyhton LED.py

The output is as expected:

```
LED on
LED off
```

But the LED doesn't turn on at all. I've tried several LEDs and changed all the cables several times. I've used different GND pins. I've changed GPIO pins (and altered the code accordingly). I've swapped resistors several times. All with no luck...

What could I be doing wrong? :-)

EDIT:
Added some pictures and screenshots in comments below!!

Comment: Everything appears correct.  That being the case the most likely explanation is wrong connections.  We need a photo to help.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmgeJ.jpg

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdjWL.jpg

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDcMD.jpg

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post more than two links in one post :-( Hope this works

Comment: That all looks correct.  Have you tried turning the LED around?  Perhaps anode/cathode are connected wrong.

Comment: Thanks so much for your replies, but grrrrrr this is so frustrating! :-)
Regarding the LED: the shorter end is connected to the resistor and then to GND. I just tried again the other (very unlikely way) and still nothing...
Could it be that I e.g. accidentally fried a circuit on the board?

Comment: Have you tested the LED? Connect the red wire directly to 3.3 volts (pin 1).

Comment: I found the problem: The purple cable is broken.... Thanks so much for your help!!